# I want read the email details of all contacts from mobile device in android

Tags: java, android

I use the code

```
phonecontactemailid = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));                    
String emailType =  cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
```

But I'm not getting the correct output, my output is

```
05-27 12:24:55.233 16564-16696/com.qagate.gandhara E/ Email Data =: 9987721100
05-27 12:24:55.233 16564-16696/com.qagate.gandhara E/ Email Type =: 2
```

Comment: Can any one help me in getting the correct data

Comment: your query should point to email uri  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI

Comment: ok Thanks Kruthik let me try that